# How to call Bing Translate function in C#?

Tags: c#, translation, windows-runtime, bing

I wrote a metro style application to call bing translator, but it didnt work. I tried to debug this program, but the UI does not respond. I can't figure if it is the URI I am using, or some other problem.

Here my code :

```
public string GetTranslatedText(string textToTranslate, string fromLang, string toLang)
{
    string translation;

    if (fromLang != toLang)
    {
        string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=" +
                    appID + "&text=" + textToTranslate + "&from=" + fromLang + "&to=" + toLang;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream strm = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strm);
            translation = sr.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ensure that you are connected to the internet.",
                        "Translator", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
            return (string.Empty);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Will not translate to the same language.", "Translator",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        return (string.Empty);
    }

    // Parse string into an XElement and get the XElement Value
    // which is returned as the translated text.
    return (XElement.Parse(translation).Value);
}
```

Comment: When you say "it didn't work"... what specifically happened?

Comment: How about just outputting text that consists of random words from the target language? I doubt that that's distinguishable from the output of the translation api.

Comment: The coding can run but didnt give any respond. I dunno am I giving wrong uri or is other problem.

Comment: Are you actually passing an appID? (Did you just edit that out before posting?)

Comment: Yup. Passing an appID. Didnt edit at all.

Comment: Where is appID defined? It isn't passed into the func as a parameter, so if the code compiles, it must be a global variable. Are you initializing it somewhere? (can we see that code)

Comment: I intializing in same folder.cs. private string appId = "*********************"; (stars is bing appId which having privacy protect. Sry, cant get show it out.)

Answer (score 2):

Since April you also need an Access Token

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to send request to 
**https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/ajax.svc/TranslateArray2**
Instead of
**http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate**